# reset week counter when crossing the new year

Tags: php, date

I am taking week number from given date, but I observed 
`date('W',strtotime("2015-12-31"));` and `date('W',strtotime("2016-01-01"));` 
 returns week number 53, because year is changed but week doesn't , so is there any way to reset week counter when crossing the new year?
Note: I am using php5.3

Comment: That's because the `1st` and up to the `3rd` is still week 53, The first new week in 2016 started January the 4'th - For 2017 the first new week will start the January the 2nd. - If you open your calendar on either your computer or phone, you'll see that (for 2016) That the `1st` and up to the `3rd` are in the same week as 28 to 31

Comment: yes you are right @Epodax, that is what I want, I want to reset week number from the start of the year

Comment: But it would be wrong, the week number resets at the first week where any of the week's days **AREN'T** part of the previous year. - I'm not sure you can force any date function to "reset" on the 1'st Jan no matter what.

Comment: @Epodax I agree that the question is falsely assuming that the way PHP does this is wrong. Which is definitely not, but I can understand why there could be a need to have a way to tell the first and last week of 2016 apart in an application.

Comment: If you want to get a week number starting from Jan 1st (rather than the ISO Week number that PHP returns with 'W') then use `$week = floor(date('z', '2016-01-01') / 7) + 1;`

Comment: @César I'm not sure I understand, if you need to keep track then you don't need to modify or do ANYTHING different. The last week in 2015 was 53, which ended January the 3rd 2016, the first week in 2016 startet January the 4'th.

Comment: @César The first and last week of a year can be easily told apart. The first "partial" week of the year is simply part of the last week of the previous year. The last "partial" week of the year is, well, the last week of the same year (which overflows into the next year, if it happens). Basically OP is attempting to redefine years of the week, which I don't see the reason to. All major timekeeping softwares follow the convention we have discussed.

Comment: @Terry I pointed out that OP is attempting to do something silly and that PHP is correct, and I'm not defending the fact that he's throwing an ISO convention out the window. He asked whether it was technically possible to number the part of the last week of this year differently from the first half. And technically, it is possible to do so with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your solution 
This checks for month and checks get week as per your requirement

```
$w=(int)date('W', strtotime('2016-01-01'));
$m=(int)date('n', strtotime('2016-01-01'));
$week = $w==1?($m==12?53:1):($w>=51?($m==1?0:$w):$w);
echo $week;
```

Answer (score 2):

While technically correct, the answer PHP gives you may not be the one you were looking for. I suppose you could keep compatibility by calling that half week "week 0"

You would have to target the next Monday and then subtract 1 to the result. This for example should work for you:

```
<?php
echo date('W', strtotime('NEXT MONDAY', strtotime('2016-01-01'))) - 1;
```

As you can see, for the first of January you get the result `int(0)` which doesn't break compatibility the rest of the year, but works nicely for the year 2016.

NOTE: You will have to fix it for the last week of December yourself. But I hope this gives you a direction you can work with.

```
echo date('m') == 1? date('W', strtotime('NEXT MONDAY', time())) - 1 : date('W', time())
```

Could be an example.